# Class Group contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods

Tags: php, oop

Hello i have a problem,

with my code, i don't know what im fix this code

**Error**

Fatal error: Class Group contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Aturan::cari) in D:\xampp\htdocs\tes\index.php on line 16

**This is my code**

```
<?php 
    interface Aturan {
        public function cari($id);
    }
    trait Bantuan {
            public function ubah_ke_string_json($str){
                return NULL;
            }
    }
    abstract class Aturan_abstrak implements Aturan {
            use Bantuan;
    }
    class Group extends Aturan_abstrak {
        protected $grup;

        public function Group($grup) {
                $this->grup = $grup;
        }
    } 
    $grup = new Group(array(
                "C" => array("administrator"),
                "A" => array("operator","staff")
            ));

    echo $grup->cari("A");
?>
```

i'm confused, help me please.

Answer (score 0):

This error means, that one or more abstract methods needs to be implemented first. In your case, method `cari` is not implemented.

Please take a look at topic [Class Abstraction](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php) for more information.

Comment: Please take a look at the error string: `Class Group contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Aturan::cari)` See http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php for more information.